# android how to set navigation drawer shifts whole activity with actionbar?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am working with drawer layout.here, navigation drawer shifts Framelayout not activity with actionbar. please provide me some links to get effect like it come upside whole activity.

Comment: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Answer (score 0):

Make the `DrawerLayout` as the root element of your layout xml. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- The main content view -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- <include layout="@layout/"/> -->
</LinearLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<fragment
    android:name="com.yeepay.mpos.money.fragment.HomeDrawerFrag"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And If you want to know details of this, check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Comment: thank you for the reply,what exact i want is to shift actionbar also. it is shifting the content view only.

Comment: What do mean `shift`? Like what?